# Is a pg_dump DB dump 'at-that-time' dump?

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I know PostgresQL `pg_dump` guarantees consistency even if DB is modified while dump is going on, but I want to know if the final dump contains any data modified/inserted after the dump started.

To elaborate:

1. Time *t*:     I start pg_dump
2. Time *t+1*:  There are updates/inserts to the database
3. Time *t+x*:  pg_dump completes.

I don't want any of the modifications done in the 'x' period to be present in the dump file.

Is this possible?

Comment: If in doubt [read the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html): "*It makes consistent backups even if the database is being used concurrently*"

Answer (score 10):

This was answered in another SO question: [Doing pg_dump while still many active transaction.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995646/doing-pg-dump-while-still-many-active-transaction)

The short answer is yes: pg_dump opens a transaction and no changes made to the database will be visible to it during the dump, so pg_dump snapshots are atomic and are a consistent snapshot (iow, no foreign key or other constraints will be violated in the snapshot).

HTH